# Is there any way to change the font/color of an excel file name sitting in a document library?

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-designer, document-library

I have a spreadsheet in a document library and somehow I have been requested to make it more visible, either by making the file name in bold, bigger or highlight it somehow.

I have SharePoint Designer 2010 and have been browsing the internet trying to find an answer to my question but unfortunately, I didn't.

Is there any chance to get this done or that's not feasible at all?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you know javaScript? I would suggest using JS to find the excel fields and highlight the <td> cell

Answer (score 1):

As I understand, you have an excel file within document library , and you need only to change the color and font size for this file :

So try to do the following :

- Edit your page that holds document library.
- Add a Content Editor web part > Edit Source. (or add the following code to txt file and upload it to SharePoint then link it to your content editor)

Add the following Javascript Code :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function disablelinkPageTitle() {
var aTags = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
var searchText = "Qassas"; // set your excel file name
var link;
for (var i = 0; i < aTags.length; i++) 
{
if (aTags[i].textContent == searchText) 
{
link = aTags[i];
link.style.color= 'red'; // Change color
link.style.fontSize= '40px'; // Change font size
break;
}}}
_spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push("disablelinkPageTitle"); 
</script>
```

**[Output]**

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer Qassas, glad to see that it is feasible to get it done. However, I have tried to follow your instructions on nothing is happening.

Comment: I opened SharePoint Designer 2010, searched the library and inserted the code changing the necessary fields in the content editor webpart. If I preview the changes in the browser I get the following error "Web Part Error: The file you imported is not valid. Verify that the file is a Web Part description file (*.webpart or *.dwp) and that it contains well-formed XML. " Maybe important: the file is stored in a sub-sharepoint site, not on main sharepoint.  I also get some error "HTML incompatibility detected"

Comment: no need For SharePoint designer , only add a content editor to your page via the browser , and add the above code .please don't hesitate to tell me if you need more clarification ,

Answer (score 0):

You can leverage SharePoint Client Side Rendering framework to do this change. [Here](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/office/Client-side-rendering-JS-2ed3538a) are few code samples which you should check out to see which fits your requirements.

Specifically, [this example](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/office/Client-side-rendering-code-0a786cdd) should be helpful.